# How to export multiple paths in library

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have one library on support, which clients use component from it like

```
import { Button } from 'ui-kit'
```

In this library, I want to do some changes to allow client select which version of `Button` they want to use, like

```
import { Button } from 'ui-kit/v2'
```

How to organize `index.ts` file to allow support this behavior?

Comment: I don't think you could, other than by intercepting module loading.  You could use generics in your code to allow the button type to be passed, with/without type guards depending on how much the interface changes from one version to the next.  I'd perhaps explore your code to see what assumptions you are making about the origin of `Button`.  You might want to design a `ButtonAdapter` that provides a common interface which would allow even more flexibility.